# R data.table interval

Tags: r, data.table, posixct

DT is data.table with POSIXct column 'date_and_time'. 
How do I use data.table syntax to add a 3 levels factor column indicating to which shift each 'date_and_time' instance belong?

```
DT <- data.table(date_and_time = as.POSIXct(
  c("1997-07-01 23:00",
    "1999-01-01 02:05",
    "2006-01-01 12:00",
    "2009-01-01 22:30",
    "2012-07-01 03:59"), required.components = 5L)
  )
shifts_delimiter = c("00:00", "08:00", "16:00")
```

required outcome:

```
> DT
         date_and_time shift
1: 1997-07-01 23:00:00     3
2: 1999-01-01 02:05:00     1
3: 2006-01-01 12:00:00     2
4: 2009-01-01 22:30:00     3
5: 2012-07-01 03:59:00     1
```

Comment: Maybe make your example a bit more reproducible and and your desired output too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use the `ITime` class that the `data.table` package provides combined with `findInterval`

```
shifts_delimiter = c("00:00", "08:00", "16:00")
DT[, Shift := findInterval(as.ITime(date_and_time), as.ITime(shifts_delimiter))]
DT
#          date_and_time Shift
# 1: 1997-07-01 23:00:00     3
# 2: 1999-01-01 02:05:00     1
# 3: 2006-01-01 12:00:00     2
# 4: 2009-01-01 22:30:00     3
# 5: 2012-07-01 03:59:00     1
```

---

Another option is to use integers as an ordered interval and use the built in `hour` function with `findInterval`

```
shifts_delimiter = c(8L, 16L, 24L)
DT[, Shift2 := findInterval(hour(date_and_time), shifts_delimiter) + 1L]
DT
#          date_and_time Shift Shift2
# 1: 1997-07-01 23:00:00     3      3
# 2: 1999-01-01 02:05:00     1      1
# 3: 2006-01-01 12:00:00     2      2
# 4: 2009-01-01 22:30:00     3      3
# 5: 2012-07-01 03:59:00     1      1
```

Answer (score 2):

If your data set is small, then a this works probably just about as good as anything.

```
DT[, shift := 1] # Default assignment
DT[hour(date_and_time) >= 8, shift := 2] # adjust for shift 2 and above
DT[hour(date_and_time) >= 16, shift := 3] # adjust for shift 3
```

Alternatively you could do a rolling join by creating a shifts table and the hour column to merge the tables together by.

```
DT[, hour := hour(date_and_time)]
setkey(DT, hour)
shift_table <- data.table(hour = hour(as.ITime(shifts_delimiter)), shift = 1:3, key = "hour")
shift_table[DT, roll = TRUE]
```

Comment: Thank you Zachary.
I liked David Arenburg solution due to its elegance.
However, your alternative solution gives me a good idea for later in the project. Rolling joints in data.table are really useful tool

Comment: That's a nice use of rolling join, you could probably shorten this to `DT[, hour := as.ITime(date_and_time)] ; data.table(hour = as.ITime(shifts_delimiter))[DT, on  = "hour", roll = TRUE, which = TRUE]`